# Adding an annotation to a class using Javassist

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, javassist

I am trying to add annotation to class dynamically using javassist

My code as follows

```
private Class addAnnotation(String className,String annotationName, int frequency) throws Exception{
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass(className);

    ClassFile classFile = ctClass.getClassFile();
    ConstPool constpool = classFile.getConstPool();

    AnnotationsAttribute annotationsAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constpool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(annotationName, constpool);
    annotation.addMemberValue("frequency", new IntegerMemberValue(classFile.getConstPool(), frequency));
    annotationsAttribute.setAnnotation(annotation);

    ctClass.getClassFile().addAttribute(annotationsAttribute);

    return ctClass.toClass();
  }
```

But the class returned does not have annotation added.

```
Class annotatedClass = addFrequencyAnnotation(MyClass.class.getSimpleName(),
          MyAnnotation.class.getSimpleName(), 10);

annotatedClass.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class); // Returns false
```

I am not sure what is missing in my code. Could someone help to identify the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should use `MyAnnotation.class.getName` rather than `MyAnnotation.class.getSimpleName`. Because there is `MyAnnotation` but no `yourpackage.MyAnnotation`.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> annotatedClass = addAnnotation(MyClass.class.getName(), MyAnnotation.class.getName(), 10);

    System.out.println(annotatedClass.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class));
  }

  private static Class<?> addAnnotation(String className, String annotationName, int frequency) throws Exception {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctClass = pool.makeClass(className + "1");//because MyClass has been defined

    ClassFile classFile = ctClass.getClassFile();
    ConstPool constpool = classFile.getConstPool();

    AnnotationsAttribute annotationsAttribute = new AnnotationsAttribute(constpool, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(annotationName, constpool);
    annotation.addMemberValue("frequency", new IntegerMemberValue(classFile.getConstPool(), frequency));
    annotationsAttribute.setAnnotation(annotation);

    ctClass.getClassFile().addAttribute(annotationsAttribute);
    return ctClass.toClass();
  }
```